# Cypher MATCH request when parameters are not known in advance

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, ecmascript-6, cypher

I'm trying to implement kind of an OGM with javascript. It wouldn't exactly be an OGM but it would work for my project.
However I need to be able to use methods like

```
User.find({ where : {name:}})
```

A bit like Sequelize would do for SQL.
However, if I try this :

```
run('MATCH (n:User {where}) RETURN ID(n) as id', { where: where });
```

Cypher answers this :

```
Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns 
(use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}")
```

Another post explains that the reason is that :

> "Unlike properties in CREATE, MATCH requires the map to be a literal. This is because the property names must be known in advance, when the query is compiled, in order to efficiently plan its execution."

Does anyone know how I can parameter a request when I don't have property names in advance ? (My GrapQL API could receive many parameters)...

Thank you very much !

Comment: You know the properties name by advance, but in your JS code. You have to generate a cypher query with a dynamically where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler version of @stdob--'s second approach (which is preferable, since it can be faster if any `User` properties specified in the query are indexed):

```
var util = require('util');

run('MATCH (n:User ' + util.inspect(where) + ') RETURN ID(n) as id');
```

I assume that the `where` object is defined within the scope of the `inspect` call.

Comment: I agree with that, but wouldn't that make me vulnerable to cypher injections ?

Comment: Since you determine the content and structure of `where`, you can make sure it s highly unlikely.

Comment: So I have to clean the parameters given through the graphql api before sending them to my functions ?

Comment: No, you just have to make sure that `where` is a map and that your user input is only used as property values.

Answer (score 2):

Some like this:

```
WITH {where} as params
MATCH (n:User) WHERE ALL(k in keys(params) WHERE params[k] = n[k])
RETURN id(n)
```

Or, as @logisma said - generate a request on the script side:

```
var params = [];
Object.keys(where).forEach( function(key) {
    var str = "`" + key + "`: " + JSON.stringify( where[key] );
    params.push( str );
});
run('MATCH (n:User {' + params.join(", ") + '}) RETURN ID(n) as id')
```

Comment: Nice. The first approach will be slow, since it requires scanning and testing every single `User` node. The second approach can be faster if any of the `User` properties specified in the query are indexed.